# C# executing Main() method without Console.Readkey() command

Tags: c#

I wrote an IMAP client app, it works fine, but i need to use "**Console.Readkey()**" in the **Main method**, without this command program not work, the main problems is that I need to use them in a DLL and not a console application, i tried various things but couldn't solve the issue, please help me in this case.

```
namespace MAIL
{
    class Program
    {
       // VARIABLES --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

        public static string EXT_IMAP_SERVER = "imap.zoho.com";
        public static int EXT_IMAP_PORT = 993;
        public static string EXT_USERNAME = "***@zohomail.com";
        public static string EXT_PASSWORD = "***";
        public static int EXT_TIMER = 5000;
        public static string DATA; 
        
        public static string EXT_IMAP_SERVER_BLOCK(string P1)
        {
            EXT_IMAP_SERVER = P1;
            return P1;
        }
        public static int EXT_IMAP_PORT_BLOCK(int P1)
        {
            EXT_IMAP_PORT = P1;
            return P1;
        }
        public static string EXT_USERNAME_BLOCK(string P1)
        {
            EXT_USERNAME = P1;
            return P1;
        }
        public static string EXT_PASSWORD_BLOCK(string P1)
        {
            EXT_PASSWORD = P1;
            return P1;
        }
               
        public static int EXT_TIMER_BLOCK(int P1)
        {
            EXT_TIMER = P1;
            return P1;
        }
        
        // MAIN BLOCK --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public static void Main()
        {
            SetTimer();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        // TIMER METHOD --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public static void SetTimer()
        {
            // Create a timer with a two second interval.
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(EXT_TIMER);
            // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
            aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            aTimer.AutoReset = true;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;

        }

        public static void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
           
                
            using (var client = new ImapClient())
            {
                client.Connect(EXT_IMAP_SERVER, EXT_IMAP_PORT, true);

                client.Authenticate(EXT_USERNAME, EXT_PASSWORD);

                // The Inbox folder is always available on all IMAP servers...
                var inbox = client.Inbox;
                inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

                //Console.WriteLine("Total messages: {0}", inbox.Count);
                //Console.WriteLine("Recent messages: {0}", inbox.Recent);

                for (int i = 0; i < inbox.Count; i++)
                {
                    var message = inbox.GetMessage(i);
                    DATA = message.Subject;
                    
                    //Console.WriteLine("Subject: {0}", message.Subject);
                    Console.WriteLine(DATA);
                }

                client.Disconnect(true);
               
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can replace timer with infinite and delay in Main

Comment: Timer start a new thread which doesn't block the main thread, using Console.ReadKey() is ok here and I think the problem will be solved by itself if it's used in a library.

Comment: Can you show me  please an example of infinite and delay ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace timer with loop and delay:

```
public static void Main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        DoAction();
        Task.Wait(5000);
    }
}

public static void DoAction()
{
    using (var client = new ImapClient())
    {
        client.Connect(EXT_IMAP_SERVER, EXT_IMAP_PORT, true);

        client.Authenticate(EXT_USERNAME, EXT_PASSWORD);

        // The Inbox folder is always available on all IMAP servers...
        var inbox = client.Inbox;
        inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

        //Console.WriteLine("Total messages: {0}", inbox.Count);
        //Console.WriteLine("Recent messages: {0}", inbox.Recent);

        for (int i = 0; i < inbox.Count; i++)
        {
            var message = inbox.GetMessage(i);
            DATA = message.Subject;
              
            //Console.WriteLine("Subject: {0}", message.Subject);
            Console.WriteLine(DATA);
        }

        client.Disconnect(true);
           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two common issues here.

For the first issue, the program actually does work, but it works so quickly that without `ReadKey()` you don't see it work. In this case better logging can help give you confidence that things are running as you expect.

I included that for completeness, but I don't think it's your situation.

The other issue has to do process and thread life cycles. In a Console app, when the Main() method/thread completes, the process ends, including any additional threads or events the process created. You fix this not by adding `Console.ReadKey()`, but rather by adding code in `Main()` to monitor and check on the status of the additional objects.

That is your issue. You set the timer, including the event, but there's no other work and so the program just finishes immediately.

There are things you can do to fix this, like adding a loop at the end of `Main` with a `Sleep()` call inside, but, **as a dll, this isn't your code's responsibility**. It's up to the code that calls into your dll to make sure the process doesn't just end. In other words, you don't really need to change anything here.